# How can I install packages on another from USB?

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, application-development

Meaning: without running `sudo apt-get install x`. (where x is the name of the app).

In Windows I'd download the app (x.exe). Save it on the USB. Then install it from the USB on the computer I want to install on.

How can I do that with Xubuntu?

Comment: `dpkg -i` will install package(s) you've provided; as will `apt` (when `apt` is given the name of the file(s) to be installed).  Note where `apt-get` will download any requirements/dependencies; `dpkg` requires those to be installed before hand, OR at the same time as the package(s) you're installing.  Same applies with `apt` though it'll go to the web for any you didn't provide (a problem if you've no internet; ie. it'll require you to have & provide them as deb's in the install command)

Comment: That link is too technical for me. Can you give me an example with the app `x`? I simple want to install an app on another machine with no internet.

Comment: The link @karel used was the better one..   You can just `wget` them using the link I provided, copy to thumb-drive then `dpkg -i` install (or `apt` depending on release; `apt` has improved in recent releases) them too....   It depends on how automated you want it.

Comment: So `sudo wget x`??

Comment: `wget` will download files from the web (or just use a web browser).  Use `man wget` to view the reference manual page for it. You can then `cp` (copy) or `mv` files/packages to the thumb-drive, walk it to your box, `mount` then `dpkg -i` (or `apt`) to install. You don't use `sudo` with `wget`, as then you won't own the files.

Comment: I'm guessing this will not be as simple as in Windows

Comment: "simple" is a relative term. You can use the GUI in the very same manner as on Windows. Download a *.deb file (by browser or wget), then use `dpkg -i filename.deb` from the shell to install it as you have brought it to the destination machine. This will get a lot harder if the package DEPENDS on other things.

Comment: Matter of fact, it does 